# getting the same message every several minutes Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

every few minutes Im getting the same mail from "microsoft outlook" and i think that it's hackers. I can't block the sender because it's write that the message from Microsoft Outlook and Outlook not allowed to block messages from microsoft outlook.

the messages are not in my language

what can I do?[image]

Comment: Contact your mail provider & change your passwords, for starters. You're being spoofed from a spammer, all you are seeing are the ones that failed to be sent, the majority of the spam will be going to real email addresses; Outlook is a big fat target. The system will automatically shut you down shortly. You need to contact the provider to regain control.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT open the email in outlook unless you take extra precautions to prevent outlook from loading HTML and image.

Such email can be anything :

i. Somebody email address book contains your name are exposed

ii. Attacker get your email address from somewhere.

iii. Your system might been infected. Go scan with antivirus program. Also check with your IT expert to determine next course of action

iv. Contact your email provider, somebody may have the open-relay open for attacker to send the spam.

Answer (score 0):

These are fake Undeliverable messages.
I also get those from time to time.

They are designed to make you either get in touch with the spammer
or logon to a website that distributes malware.

The best defense is either to ignore them and delete,
or get an extension that can bounce them right back as Undeliverable.

On the slim chance that your computer is compromised, do a few anti-virus
scans. Read also the answers to this post :
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit),
but I repeat that it is not very likely that you are infected.

Comment: How can you actually tell if they're fake? I had a similar incident about a month ago; 250 of them inside 5 minutes. My provider shut down the account & I had to jump through several hoops to get it back. My machine wasn't compromised, my provider said the account itself wasn't compromised, but someone had been using the address as the return address for their spam, so of course I was getting all the bounces.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I can't guarantee that, so also listed the alternative, but I had my share of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting spam/phishing messages. For tips about spotting and report phishing mails, hopefully you can find the following official article helpful:
[Protect yourself from phishing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033787/windows-protect-yourself-from-phishing)